# What version(s) of SSL/TLS does Active Directory support?

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ldap, tls

I'm running a pair of 2012R2 RODCs behind a load balancer for authentication for certain applications (mostly on Linux).  LDP.exe works fine for lookups, but we're having an issue with Postgres where it seems to want to use a TLS version that Active Directory does not support.  The problem is that I cannot seem to find any documentation on what versions of SSL/TLS Active Directory supports.

Does anyone have any better insight on this than my research has determined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSL/TLS versions are not linked to Active Directory, the ciphers supported is part of the operating system/configuration.

SSL 2.0, 3.0
TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2015/12/08/speaking-in-ciphers-and-other-enigmatic-tonguesupdate/

---

With LDAP connections to 636/3269, it may sometimes be necessary to enable the following registry value:

```
Key: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP  
Value: UseHostnameAsAlias  
Value type: REG_DWORD  
Value data: 1
```